# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing an MVC 4 application at work and i'm stuck with this problem.

I have an entity called `'FormaFarmaceutica'` which only has a description field. As it only has one field, the creation and edition views are loaded in a modal window using ajax. The modal window is defined in the Index view of the same controller.

There is no problem with the creation, when i click on the 'Add' button, the modal window shows and as i submit, the new entry in the database appears.

In the edit operation, when i click on the 'Edit' button, the modal window is shown, with the value that i want to edit already loaded. But **when i submit the form**, i get this 'parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' ' error.

Here's the code:

Edit view:

```
@model Dominio.formafarmaceutica

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "FormaFarmaceutica", FormMethod.Post, new { id =       "add_form", role = "form" })) 
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div class = "form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" value="@Model.Descripcion" />
</div>                             
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar cambios</button>

}
```

Modal window & script where this view is loaded:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="modalAgregar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-   labelledby="agregar" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Descripcion</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="modal">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

  $(function (e) {
    forma farmaceutica.$("#editarFormaFarmaceutica").click(function () {
        var idForma = $(this).val();
        var load = "@Url.Action("Edit", "FormaFarmaceutica")" + "?id=" + idForma.toString();
        $("#modal").load(load);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        if (Session["Username"] != null)
        {
            if (user.HasAccess((int)Session["UserID"], (int)Operaciones.FormaFarmaceutica.Editar))
            {
                try
                {
                    formafarmaceutica f = db.FindSingle<formafarmaceutica>(aux => aux.ID == id && aux.Activo == 1);
                    if (f != null)
                    {
                        f.Descripcion = collection["descripcion"];
                        db.Update<formafarmaceutica>(f);

                        Logger.Log.Registrar((int)Operaciones.FormaFarmaceutica.Editar, (string)Session["Username"], f.Descripcion);

                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "FormaFarmaceutica");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        ViewBag.Errors = "Ocurrió un error al guardar los cambios.";
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "FormaFarmaceutica");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ViewBag.Errors = "Ocurrió un error al guardar los cambios.";
                    Logger.Log.Error((int)Operaciones.FormaFarmaceutica.Editar, e.InnerException.Message);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "FormaFarmaceutica");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Error");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Error");
        }
    }
```

**FIX:**

There was missing an id field on the form. I added a hidden input with the id. Thanks for the help!

```
    @model Dominio.formafarmaceutica

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "FormaFarmaceutica", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "add_form", role = "form" })) 
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class = "form-group">
             <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" value="@Model.ID" />
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" value="@Model.Descripcion" />
       </div>                             
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar cambios</button>

    }
```

Comment: Have you checked what idForma is (var idForma = $(this).val();) before posting to the server?

Comment: Yes, that is used to load the edit view, which works fine. Submitting the form is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition for you edit post action is:

`public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)`

Yet there is nothing in your form in your edit view that it can bind to the id parameter.

Comment: Thanks! In the edit view i added a hidden input with the id as value and it worked!
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" value="@Model.ID" />

Comment: You could also just do `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID)`

Answer (score 0):

As `jQuery.load` is a get method, you need to change your Action `HttpMethod` to `HttpGet`. This might resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...

You are using JQuery.load(...)... http://api.jquery.com/load/ that effectively performs a get request but the action is a Post action

Either use a jQuery post request or mark the action as [HttpGet]. The fact that you are also expecting a FormCollection indicates that you want to do a post ergo it should be a jQuery post. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: I think the jquery load calls a get method he hasn't show that returns the view that then allows the submission of the form (at the top titled edit view), which in turn should hit the controller action.

Comment: @BenRobinson you could be right but it's not clear what the intention is from the code samples

Comment: I agree it is confusing, but i think i managed to work it out, mostly by educated guesswork ;-)